# Stata esttab/LaTeX Error: Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr

Tags: syntax, latex, stata

Combining and modifying this code (http://www.stata.com/statalist/archive/2012-11/msg00756.html) and this code (http://www.stata.com/statalist/archive/2009-02/msg00023.html), I try to use `esttab` (part of `estout`) in Stata to export a file that can be compiled in LaTeX. A real application of this might involve a complicated summary statistics table where one is pulling the statistics from several different sources and thus needs to utilize matrices. I am getting an error, however, in LaTeX when I compile. The error is:

```
Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr.
```

Stata code:

```
clear all
eststo clear
mat A = (1,2\5,6)
mat coln A = male:1979 male:2007
mat rown A = mystat
ereturn post
estadd matrix B = A'
eststo MaleLabel
mat A = (3,4\7,8)
mat coln A = female:1979 female:2007
mat rown A = mystat
ereturn post
estadd matrix B = A'
eststo FemaleLabel
esttab MaleLabel FemaleLabel using "esttab.tex", ///
    cell((B["1979"]B["2007"])) booktabs ///
    mgroups("Male" "Female", pattern(1 1) prefix(\multicolumn{@span}{c}{) suffix(}) span erepeat(\cmidrule(lr){@span})) ///
    noobs replace nomtitles nonum
```

LaTeX code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article} 
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htbp]
\begin{center}
\input{esttab}
\end{center}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

The file that is produced from `esttab` is:

```
{
\def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi}
\begin{tabular}{l*{2}{c}}
\toprule
            &\multicolumn{2}{c}{Male} &\multicolumn{2}{c}{Female}\\\cmidrule(lr){2-3}\cmidrule(lr){4-5}
            &        1979&        2007&        1979&        2007\\
\midrule
mystat      &           1&           2&           3&           4\\
mystat      &           5&           6&           7&           8\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
}
```

Now, I can get things to work if I tweak this line:

```
 \begin{tabular}{l*{2}{c}}
```

to be:

```
 \begin{tabular}{l*{2}{cc}}
```

(I added an extra `c`.)

But I only know how to do this manually. What can I change in the Stata code to make this happen automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this simple option to your estab code

`prehead({\begin{tabular}{l*{2}{cc}}\toprule)`

and you are all set my man!

Comment: I think you might need to change the last `}` to `{` so the full prehead would be `prehead(\begin{tabular}{l*{2}{cc}}{)`

Comment: Almost works. It should be: `prehead({\begin{tabular}{l*{2}{cc}}\toprule)` Can you update your answer?